# Is it possible to download an entire YouTube Playlist using Java, more specifically Android Studio

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

I know that this is relatively easy using python but is there anyway to do this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by download [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)

> Returns a collection of playlist items that match the API request parameters. You can retrieve all of the playlist items in a specified playlist or retrieve one or more playlist items by their unique IDs.

If you want to download the actual video then no the YouTube api does not let you download videos.

Check out the google api java client library

Comment: Do you have any code for getting the url of videos in a Playlist using Java?